# First overlay text not lasting

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this snippet of code, adding two overlayed texts with same effects/durations in two different part of my video.

```
-i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "color=black:100x100,format=yuva444p[c];[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv0]; [ct]setsar=1,split=2[t1][t2]; [t1]drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:text='Pippo':fontcolor=white:fontsize=32:box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2 - 20,fade=t=in:st=6:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=19:d=2:alpha=1[txta1];[t2]drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:text='Topolino':fontcolor=white:fontsize=32:box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2 + 20,fade=t=in:st=6:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=19:d=2:alpha=1[txta2];[mv0][txta1]overlay=0:0:shortest=1[mv1];[mv1][txta2]overlay=0:0:shortest=1" "output.mp4"
```

Somewhy, the second text, "`Topolino`" lasts perfectly from the fade-in to the fade-out.

The first text ("`Pippo`") is appearing and disappearing immediatly.

They have the same effect, so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

---

**Edit: added output**

> Error: ffmpeg version N-90893-gcae6f806a6 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the
>   FFmpeg developers
>
> Error:   built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
>
> Error:   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2
>   --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
>
> Error:   libavutil      56. 17.100 / 56. 17.100
>
> Error:   libavcodec     58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
>
> Error:   libavformat    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
>
> Error:   libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
>
> Error:   libavfilter     7. 21.100 /  7. 21.100
>
> Error:   libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
>
> Error:   libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
>
> Error:   libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
>
> Error: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\AREA\video.mp4':
>
> Error:   Metadata:
>
> Error:     major_brand     : isom
>
> Error:     minor_version   : 512
>
> Error:     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>
> Error:     encoder         : Lavf58.13.100
>
> Error:   Duration: 00:02:12.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3149 kb/s
>
> Error:     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661),
>   yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1024x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 128:75], 3014 kb/s, 24 fps,
>   24 tbr, 19200 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       handler_name    : VideoHandler
>
> Error:       timecode        : 00:00:00:00
>
> Error:     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D),
>   44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
>
> Error:     Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
>
> Error:       timecode        : 00:00:00:00
>
> Error: Fontconfig  error: Cannot load default config file
>
> Error: [Parsed_drawtext_5 @ 000002a7c251ea00] Using
>   "C:/WINDOWS/fonts/mingliub.ttc"
>
> Error: Fontconfig  error: Cannot load default config file
>
> Error: [Parsed_drawtext_8 @ 000002a7c2c52a00] Using
>   "C:/WINDOWS/fonts/mingliub.ttc"
>
> Error: Stream mapping:
>
> Error:   Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale2ref:ref (graph 0)
>
> Error:   overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
>
> Error:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
>
> Error: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>
> Error: Fontconfig  error: Cannot load default config file
>
> Error: [Parsed_drawtext_5 @ 000002a7c3e6aec0] Using
>   "C:/WINDOWS/fonts/mingliub.ttc"
>
> Error: Fontconfig  error: Cannot load default config file
>
> Error: [Parsed_drawtext_8 @ 000002a7c3e6ac80] Using
>   "C:/WINDOWS/fonts/mingliub.ttc"
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] using SAR=1/1
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] using cpu capabilities: MMX2
>   SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] profile High, level 3.1
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 -
>   H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 -
>   http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3
>   deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
>   mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0
>   deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12
>   lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
>   bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
>   b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
>   keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
>   mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
>   aq=1:1.00
>
> Error: Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\AREA\output_text.mp4':
>
> Error:   Metadata:
>
> Error:     major_brand     : isom
>
> Error:     minor_version   : 512
>
> Error:     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>
> Error:     encoder         : Lavf58.13.100
>
> Error:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661),
>   yuv420p, 1024x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 128:75], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24
>   tbc (default)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       encoder         : Lavc58.19.100 libx264
>
> Error:     Side data:
>
> Error:       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay:
>   -1
>
> Error:     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D),
>   44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
>
> Error:     Metadata:
>
> Error:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
>
> Error:       encoder         : Lavc58.19.100 aac
>
> Error: frame=   61 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.83
>   bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=5.65x
>
> Error: frame=  137 fps=136 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:05.99
>   bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=5.94x
>
> [...]
>
> Error: frame= 3180 fps= 88 q=-1.0 Lsize=   16533kB time=00:02:12.51
>   bitrate=1022.0kbits/s speed=3.65x
>
> Error: video:14352kB audio:2080kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB
>   global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.611671%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] frame I:14    Avg QP:17.18  size:
>   42960
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] frame P:1170  Avg QP:20.09  size: 
>   9916
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] frame B:1996  Avg QP:21.54  size: 
>   1249
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] consecutive B-frames:  3.3% 38.3% 
>   2.5% 56.0%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] mb I  I16..4: 27.0% 61.1% 11.8%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] mb P  I16..4:  4.3%  5.8%  0.3% 
>   P16..4: 34.6%  9.8%  7.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:38.0%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  0.5%  0.0% 
>   B16..8: 19.5%  0.9%  0.1%  direct: 2.0%  skip:76.6%  L0:39.8% L1:55.2%
>   BI: 5.0%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] 8x8 transform intra:57.0%
>   inter:84.0%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 33.3%
>   65.4% 24.9% inter: 10.4% 17.5% 2.4%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] i16 v,h,dc,p: 59% 17% 12% 13%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35%
>   15% 33%  2%  3%  3%  3%  3%  2%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36%
>   18% 13%  4%  6%  7%  6%  6%  4%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] i8c dc,h,v,p: 52% 17% 24%  7%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] Weighted P-Frames: Y:29.0%
>   UV:17.2%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] ref P L0: 65.1% 15.7% 14.5%  4.3% 
>   0.5%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] ref B L0: 89.7%  8.2%  2.1%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] ref B L1: 98.1%  1.9%
>
> Error: [libx264 @ 000002a7c2a9d800] kb/s:887.30
>
> Error: [aac @ 000002a7c24a6e00] Qavg: 179.786
>
> Error:

Comment: Your command overlays both at the same position. Shift one of them.

Comment: @Gyan hi! thanks for the comment, they are actually shifted (one is + 20 and the other one -20 on Y axes), I can see both on the screen, but the first disappear after 3 seconds

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan added, I cut some of "frame/speed" output and replaced them with `[...]` since they were all the same. Thanks